# Using Loops to print patterns

Tags: java

Hey guys so I'm working on a problem where I need to print

```
1 2 3 4 5 6
1 2 3 4 5
1 2 3 4
1 2 3 
1 2
1
```

```java
public class Set_5_P5_18b {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int x;
        String y;
        x = 1;
        y = "";

        System.out.println("Pattern B:");
        while (x < 7) {
            y = y + x + " ";
                x++;  
        }
        System.out.println(y);

    }

}
```

What I wrote above print's the first line but I can't figure out how to modify it to print the second, could anyone help me please?

Comment: What have you tried? You need another loop. Note that SO is not a debugger.

Comment: Where's the second line?

Comment: Start with n=6 and print i=0 to n, and decrement n for each step...

Comment: You want a nested loop (a loop inside another loop).

Comment: I can't figure out how to use a nested loop to get the second line

Answer (score 1):

Yuo need the outer for loop to run for say x ranging from values 6 to 1. For each value of x you need a inner loop that runs for values 1 ... x and prints out values in a line.

Keep this in mind and try to come up with pseudo code first and then the implementation code.

Answer (score 0):

Your output can be observed like a 2-dimensional array where:

- index `i` grows top-to-bottom and represents row index
- index `j` grows left-to-right and represents column index

[image]

What you are doing right now is iterating over the columns of the first row and that is it.
As mentioned in the comments, you should add a second loop to iterate over the rows as well.

Here is how you can achieve this with two `for` loops:

```
int colSize = 6;
int rowSize = 6;
for(int i = 1; i <= rowSize; i++) {
    for(int j = 1; j <= colSize; j++) {
        System.out.print(j + " ");      // print individual column values
    }
    System.out.println();               // print new line for the next row
    colSize--;                          // decrement column size since column size decreases after each row
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you'd have to reset the variables x, when you quit while :P

Answer (score 0):

So commonly when you are writing a for loop and you realize that you want a certain aspect of the for loop to change each time the program iterates, 9/10 times you want to use nested for loops (for loop within a for loop).

So essentially every time that you iterate through the for loop you want to have the duration of the for loop decrease. So...

`for (int num =1; num < <number that you want to change>; num++) {}`

Here is the code method.

```
public static void print(int x) {
    for (int lengthOfFor = x; lengthOfFor > 0; lengthOfFor--) {
        for (int num = 1; num <= lengthOfFor; num++) {
            System.out.print(num + " ");
        }
        System.out.print("\n");
    }
}
```

This is how you would do call the method.

```
public class print
{
    public static void print(int x) {
        for (int lengthOfFor = x; lengthOfFor > 0; lengthOfFor--) {
            for (int num = 1; num <= lengthOfFor; num++) {
                System.out.print(num + " ");
            }
            System.out.print("\n");
        }
    }
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        print(6);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[java-8](/questions/tagged/java-8) solution:

```
public static void printPattern(int rows) {
    IntStream.range(0, rows).map(r -> rows - r).forEach(x -> {
        IntStream.rangeClosed(1, x).forEach(y -> {
            System.out.print(String.format("%3d", y));
        });
        System.out.println();
    });
}
```

Usage:

```
printPattern(9);
```

Output:

```
1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9
1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8
1  2  3  4  5  6  7
1  2  3  4  5  6
1  2  3  4  5
1  2  3  4
1  2  3
1  2
1
```